# обновить denwer

Tags: php, denwer

друзья подскажите почему когда я обновляю денвер после запуска не подключается php5apache [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написано же вроде ясно - "синтаксическая ошибка в файле-конфигурации .../httpd.conf на строке 163"

Comment: согласен, причину апач написал сам вполне понятную. и посмотрите на досуге в сторону openserver, за всё время что сижу на нем таких проблем не возникало, да и удобнее на много(даже плюхи есть)

Comment: где тут может быть отпечатка: tajshare.tj/download.php?file=e967d6b7-58b8-11e6-b89b-00e0815e47ee

Comment: @mega94 а что в файле конфигурации вообще делает эта ссылка? удаляйте эту хрень. Что то типо бредовой рекламы

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев ага так вообще денвер качает адреса сайтов на денвере.

Comment: @mega94 мой косяк, я подумал что эта ссылка, являющаяся вашей картинкой, вставлена в конфиг. Кто на такие ресурсы скриншоты выкидывает?)

Answer (score 1):

дело было в apache скачал вот этот архив и все: http://berezovskiy.org.ua/goto/http://phpdev.toolsforresearch.com/php-5.5.9-Win32-VC11-x86.zip

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник, при необходимости. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.